# How to modify values in m2m field in form? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models in my `models.py`. They are **Doctor** and **Specialty**:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    specialties = ManyToManyField('Specialty', related_name='doctors')
    mc_id = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Specialty(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    mc_id = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When i'm creating new Doctor instance via admin interface (`change_form.html` template) I see my **Doctor** model fields, which I should fill with data. Among these fields there is a field ***specialties*** ("Cпециальности"), which is m2m field and contains *names* (as I set `__str__(self)` method in **Specialty** model to return `self.name`) for *specialties* which were previously added to `Specialty` model ([see a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqfCy.png)).

All I want is to see in this list not only *specialty names*, but also values of *mc_id* field of **Specialty** model, but it is not my case to make it at the expense of something like this:

```
class Specialty(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    mc_id = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '(' + self.mc_id + ')'
```

I thought i could make it through overriding of `formfield_for_manytomany()` method in my admin model (associated with `Doctor` model) in `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "specialties":
            queryset = Specialty.objects.all()
            for specialty in queryset:
                specialty.name += '(' + {specialty.mc_id} + ')'
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

It didn't work. I'd like to know how can i solve my problem. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: I'd also like to make a content of *specialties* field in the form user-dependent:

- if *superuser*  tries to add new doctor he will see in the *specialties* field of the form values like:

  - Internal Medicine (mc1_id)
  - Neurology (mc1_id)
  - Cardiology (mc2_id)
- if *normal user* which name is 'mc1_id' tries to add new doctor he will see in the form values filtered by his name and without '(mc_id)'-part. Like:

  - Internal Medicine
  - Neurology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that overwrite the `label_from_instance` method in the form field can work for you.

```py
class SpecialtyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        obj.name + '(' + obj.mc_id + ')'


class DoctorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    specialties = SpecialtyModelMultipleChoiceField(
        Specialty.objecs.all
        # ....
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DoctorModelForm
    # ....
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to make the field text user dependent you can return different classes in the `get_form` method of the `Admin Model`:

```py
class SpecialtyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        obj.name + '(' + obj.mc_id + ')'


class DoctorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    specialties = SpecialtyModelMultipleChoiceField(
        Specialty.objecs.all
        # ....
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'


class SimpleDoctorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kw):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return DoctorModelForm
        return SimpleDoctorModelForm
```

If you need more, you can set properties in the form and work with its in the constructor:

```py
class DoctorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'

    @classmethod
    def set_user(cls, user):
        cls.__user = user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(DoctorModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        if self.__user.condition:
            self.fields['specialties'] = MyCustomField


@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DoctorModelForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kw):        
        form_class = super(DoctorAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kw)
        form_class.set_user(request.user)

        return form_class
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Could you please clarify, if there is a way to make the result user-dependent? I updated my question with a description of what i mean by this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help! It's a perfect fit solution. I also considered slightly different realisation of this idea. I shared it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use format() in models

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.mc_id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't solve my problem this way. I made an update of the start post, where I described why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share an altnernative realisation of **Tonio's** great idea.

```
# fields.py

class SpecialtyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        obj.name + '(' + obj.mc_id + ')'
```

```
# admin.py

class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        # some logic
        return form

@admin.register(Doctor)
class DoctorAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "specialties":
            queryset = Specialty.objects.all().filter(mc_id=request.user)
            kwargs.update({'queryset': queryset})
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            form.base_fields['specialties'] = SpecialtyModelMultipleChoiceField(Specialty.objects.all())
        return form
```

I think it can be useful in situations when `DoctorAdmin` is inherited from some base model like `BaseAdmin` and this base model also has overriden `get_form()` method. But here in case of superuser's request queryset is formed twice, therefore **Tonio's** answer is definetely better.